# TO replace Present participle (WINNING) with a past participle (WON) in sentence

Tags: grammar

> Not only is she an award-winning singer, but she also is a good sport person.

If I used part participle "**WON**" in lieu of Winning, is it wrong? And why?

Comment: Listen up @user462169 The answer to your question is "award-winning", **not** *"award-won". Please take that on board.

Comment: Did you do any research on this before asking? If you search, "award-won singer", do you get more or fewer results than "award-winning singer"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The present participle ***winning*** is what you need here, because you want you phrase to mean ***a singer who wins or has won awards*** (active meaning). Within the modifier *award-winning*, ***winning*** refers to *singer* as its agent, ***not awards***.

Past participles are used with passive meanings. So ***a won award*** would mean, *an award that was won*. Note that **a won-award singer* makes no sense.

> The *present participle* is used ***as an active adjective***. The active adjective describes the effect on people or things:
>
> - He's an ***interesting*** professor. I'd like to take a class with him.
>
> The *past participle* is used ***as a passive adjective***.
>
> - Any ***interested*** student should apply in the office. ([Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/present-and-past-participles-explained-1211104))

Let's take another example:

> - Such an ***annoying*** noise! (active meaning: *The noise annoys me*.)
> - The ***annoyed*** man went out slamming the door. (passive meaning: *The man was annoyed by something*.)

Comment: Thank you, but I found a in this link(Thought.co) that is - That's the man remembered by his friends. - (That is the man who was remembered by his friends.)

Comment: Yes, it is not the man who remembers, he is remembered by his friends. So _remembered_ here is passive.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "winning" modifies "singer". "Award-winning" is a verb-centred compound adjective. It's the whole compound word "award-winning" that modifies "singer.

Comment: It means a singer who wins (or won or has won awards. The compounds with a past participle generally correspond to syntactic passives with a PP, e.g. "drug-related" = "related to drugs", "home-made" = "made at home" and the like. This seems to explain why we cannot have "award-won" with a past participle as head.

Comment: Why does  it contain(IS) in lieu of WAS because it is in present tense - "That's the man remembered by his friends. - (That is the man who was remembered by his friends.)"

Comment: @user462169 "This is the man who **is** (always) remembered by his friends." Both verbs can be present.

Comment: @WS2 The student is interested by this matter because this matter interests (is of interest to) him. This student is interesting, because he interests (is of interest to) me. It is true that with linking verbs the active-passive meaning is more difficult to discern, but it is there.

Comment: @user462169 Think of **remembered** as an adjective that can be used after any tense.

Comment: @fev Ok. I see your point. We are not deling with active and passive voice, but a different sense of active and passive. (I'm afraid the system does not allow me to negate my downvote.) But I do think it needs better explanation in your answer.

Comment: @fev So our OP's postulation of a "won singer" would be a singer who had been won! Like in a raffle? Or perhaps an opera singer who had been "won over" - e.g to perform "Knees up Mother Brown" when the entire party was drunk.

Comment: @WS2 Because of the presence of "award" with a hyphen, the phrase would be basically ungrammatical. I believe the OP is confused between the notion of "awards being WON" and "the singer WINNING awards".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138660/discussion-on-answer-by-fev-to-replace-present-participle-winning-with-a-past).